# invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF62

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I am getting the following message when I type 'sudo apt update' in the terminal:

```
W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to add GPG key for the ddeb repository.

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2EDC64DC5AEE1F6B9C621F0C8CAB6595FDFF622

sudo apt-get update
```